# data doesn't save in database using PDO

Tags: php, android, mysql, pdo

I'm using `PDO` to save data to the database but the data doesn't seem to be saved, plus even it doesn't throw an error.
I'm using Android's `OKhttp3` class to send `POST` requests to my PHP file named `chatroom.php`.

```
<?PHP
include("PDOConnection.php");

//Define some value
define("ACTION_ADD_ROOM","addRoom");
define("ACTION_SELECT","select");
define("RESULT_SUCCESS",0);
define("RESULT_ERROR",1);
define("RESULT_ROOM_EXISTS",2);

$action=$_POST["action"];
$result=RESULT_ERROR;

if(isset($action))
{
    if($action==ACTION_ADD_ROOM)
    {
        $name=$_POST["name"];
        $chatdesc=$_POST["chatdesc"];

        if(isset($_FILES['chatImage'])) 
            $image=$_FILES['chatImage']['name'];

    }
    else if($action==ACTION_SELECT)
    {
        $Id=$_POST["id"];   
    }

    if(ACTION_ADD_ROOM==$action )
    {
        //check exists Room
        if(isExistRoom($cnn,$name))
        {
            $result=RESULT_ROOM_EXISTS;
        }
        else
        {
            insertChatroom($cnn,$name,$chatdesc,$image);
            $result=RESULT_SUCCESS;
        }
    }
    else if(ACTION_SELECT==$action)
    {
        if(login($cnn,$Id))
        {
            $result=RESULT_SUCCESS;
            //login success
        }
        else
        {
            //login fail
            $result=RESULT_ERROR;
        }
    }

    if((isset($_FILES['chatImage']) && $result==RESULT_SUCCESS && ACTION_ADD_ROOM==$action))
    {
        $errors= array();
        $file_name = $_FILES['chatImage']['name'];
        $file_size =$_FILES['chatImage']['size'];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['chatImage']['tmp_name'];
        $file_type=$_FILES['chatImage']['type'];

        $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

        if(empty($errors)==true)
        {
            $id=returnID($cnn,$name);

            if(!is_dir("uploads/Rooms/".$id))
                mkdir("uploads/Rooms/".$id, 0700);

            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/Rooms/".$id."/".$file_name);
        }else{
            print_r($errors);
      }
   }
}

echo $result;
function insertChatroom($cnn,$name,$chatdesc,$image)
{
    try
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO chatroom (name, 'chatdesc', image) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = $cnn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute([$name, $chatdesc, $image]);
    }
    catch(\PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "ERROR  " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

function isExistRoom($cnn,$name)
{
    $query="SELECT * FROM chatroom WHERE name == ?";
    $stmt=$cnn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(1,$name);
    $stmt->execute();

    $rowcount=$stmt->rowCount();
    //for debug
    //var_dump($rowcount);
    return $rowcount;
}

function login($cnn,$Email,$Password)
{
    return 1;
}

function returnID($cnn,$name)
{
    $query="SELECT * FROM chatroom WHERE name = ? ";
    $stmt=$cnn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(1,$name);

    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchColumn();

    //for debug
    //var_dump($rowcount);
    return $result;
}
?>
```

I think there is no different between sending `POST` request using a HTML page or from Android but just in case, here is my code for Android:

```
 package com.example.android.chatroom.Activities.RegisterActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import com.example.android.chatroom.Tags;
import com.example.android.chatroom.chatroom;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.MultipartBody;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;


public class ChatroomNetworkCallTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    ProgressBar mProgress;
    FloatingActionButton btnRegister;
    View view;
    Context context;
    //Activity ReciveActivity;
    File imageFile;
    chatroom Rooms=new chatroom();
    public static String Result;
    private static final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE = MediaType.parse("image/*");
    private static final String IMGUR_CLIENT_ID = "...";
    private OkHttpClient client=new OkHttpClient();
    public ChatroomNetworkCallTask(chatroom Rooms, File ImageFile, Context mconext,View view)
    {
        this.context=mconext;
        if(ImageFile!=null) {
            this.imageFile = ImageFile;
            Log.d("getrealfile:", "NEtwork:  " + imageFile.getName() + " And Absolute: " + imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }else
        {
            Log.d("getrealfile:","Image not set to update");
        }
        this.Rooms=Rooms;
        this.view=view;
        mProgress= Rooms.getPbar();
        btnRegister=Rooms.getBtnSend();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        if(mProgress!=null)
            mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (btnRegister!=null)
            btnRegister.setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            Log.d("FIlePath:",imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
            RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                        .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                        .addFormDataPart("action", Rooms.getStatus())
                        .addFormDataPart("name", Rooms.getChatroomName())
                        .addFormDataPart("chatdesc", Rooms.getChatroomDesc())
                         .addFormDataPart("chatImage", "imgRoom.jpg",
                            RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE, imageFile))

                        .build();


            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .header("Authorization", "Client-ID " + IMGUR_CLIENT_ID)
                    .url(Tags.ChatroomAddress)
                    .post(requestBody)
                    .build();

            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

            Result=response.body().string().toString();
            Log.d("resultValue:",Result);
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(Result);
            StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
            while (m.find()) { build.append(m.group()); }


            return build.toString();




        }  catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return  null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String o) {
        super.onPostExecute(o);
        Log.d("valueOfo:",""+o);
        String msg = null;

        if(o != null && o.trim().matches(".*\\d+.*")){

            switch (o.toString().trim().toString().trim()) {
                case "0":
                    msg = "اطلاعات شما با موفقیت ثبت شد";
                    break;
                case "1":
                    msg = "خطا در ثبت اطلاعات";
                    break;
                default:
                    msg="خطایی بس ناجوانمردانه";
            }

        }



       Snackbar.make(view, msg != null ? msg : "لطفا مجددا تلاس فرمایید",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if(mProgress!=null)
            mProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        btnRegister.setEnabled(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: why don't you start with simple POST example and see if it works, then we can debug/check your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add `$cnn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` to your code so `PDO` actually throws exceptions. You will then get an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''chatdesc', image)

This is caused by the single quotes in your query. Remove those and it'll probably work